# is there a way to collect output from reducer in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a way to collect the output from a reducer and prevent it from writing to file? I'd like to sort the reduced output before writing to file.

Comment: Can you some more information like, what is input for Reduce, What is the output of the reducer and what key or value you want to sort?

Comment: @JRR, the reducer's outputs are already sorted by key. What else sorting you might require?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do it. MapReduce job must be finished writing result to file.

If I understand correctly you want to sort reducers output in a certain way instead of default sorting by keys passed to reducer.

You have 2 possible ways for this:

1. Change output key on Map phase to another one by which your data
   should be sorted on Reduce phase.
2. if 1st way is impossible you can
       sort reducers output by another MapReduce job or different tools.
       You can start sorting job right after the main job from the same
       driver specifying the output directory of the main job as the input
       directory for the sorting job.